# Loopback time based operations

Tags: datetime, time, model, loopback, operation

I'm working with loopback , but now i want to perform some operation on my data after a certain time automaticaly
Precioulsly I have a model called `Canal` and my model has a field `beginDate` and `endDate` of type `Date`, `beginDate`is set to today date , and `endDate`is set to `beginDate`plus two dates , so I want to delete `Canal` whom `endDate` is expired

Any ideas how to process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) to add something like a cron job and run it in specific time each day and delete expired Canals.

You should define it as a [boot script](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-boot-scripts.html) in LoopBack.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that , but what if a `Canal`expire before the schedule start the task!??  I found an alternative solution , I think I'll keep that solution for the moment

Comment: Could you share the answer in this site?